# Jquery getting values of multiple select not working

Tags: jquery, select, multiple-select

I have a simple multiple select which I am trying to send its selected values via ajax.
I can use alert and it show the values selected to me but it goes through as blank in ajax.
To test this, i tried to the replace and that doesn't work either. so there is something wrong and I can't figure it out!

```
<select id="multiple" multiple="multiple">
<option value="Text 1">Text 1</option>
<option value="Text 2">Text 2</option>
<option value="Text 3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

If I choose options 2 and 3 the alert will show my selection like this:

var test = $("#multiple").val();
   alert(test); will return: Text 2,Text 3

and if I use replace it doesn't work, IE:

test = test.replace(",", ", ");

I thought, this might be an array and tried to convert it to string and still it didn't work!

Comment: It is an array.  What do you mean you tried to convert it to a string?

Comment: What do you mean by "it goes through as blank in ajax". Could you show the ajax code?

Comment: can you share the ajax request code... and have a look at your browser network tab(developer tools) to see what is the actual data that is being sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `test` is an array so there is no `array` method called `replace`

instead you can use the [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method like

```
test = test.join(", ");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y6av4j7v/)

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

> In the case of select elements, it returns null when no option is
>   selected and an array containing the value of each selected option
>   when there is at least one and it is possible to select more because
>   the multiple attribute is present.

When you call [alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) and pass an array as you have done, the array will be converted to a string by calling the [Array.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) method, which will display each member of the array separated by coma(`,`)

Comment: Judging from the question, this doesn't exactly solve the issue; it just explains that it's an array. The problem seems to be using that value in an AJAX request.

Comment: @Arun P Johny, this made it work and thank you for the explanation!